# Namespaces in Imports field not imported from: All declared Imports should be used

Tags: r, r-package

I am working on my R package. I am getting this error:

```
Namespaces in Imports field not imported from:
   ‘kableExtra’ ‘ranger’
  All declared Imports should be used.
```

I get this error with `devtools::check_rhub()` i.e. on linux and windows platform. When I check my package locally (mac os) with  `devtools::check()` all checks gets passed successfully.

I looked deeper into the imports of my description file, currently I am doing:

```
Imports:  
    ranger(>= 0.10.1),
    Metrics(>= 0.1.3),
    kableExtra(>= 0.9.0)
```

I am using functions from `ranger` and `kableExtra` using `::` like `ranger::function_name`, `kableExtra::function_name` since there are just one or two functions I need.

I am not doing `importFrom` in Namespace file. Because, like I said, there are just 1 or 2 functions I need to borrow.

Why am I getting this error ? What am I missing ?

Comment: @Suren is incorrect, you do need `Imports: ranger` in the `DESCRIPTION` file even with the `::` notation.  The problem is that the check code sometimes misses uses of `::`, so some of the notes are spurious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed the problem with this workaround:

1. Add the name of the package in `Namespace` file with `importFrom`.
2. Doesn't matter if you are borrowing just one function from a package using `::`, if the package name is mentioned in the `Imports` or `Depends`, it will raise an error.

Comment: For people using Roxygen, just add `@importFrom <package> <function-name>` somewhere in the package. That way during the documentation step it's added to the NAMESPACE file (and won't show up in the actual documentation of the function). See for example the setup step in the vignette of Rdpack: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rdpack/index.html

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it causes the imported package to be loaded when the using package was loaded.  Using `pkg::fn` notation delays the load until it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

When the error is related to the package `Rdpack`

```
Namespace in Imports field not imported from: 'Rdpack'
```

it is more subtle as we do not use directly this package (it is used internally during `devtools::check()`. The Rdpack documentation indicates that this line:

```
# ' @importFrom Rdpack reprompt
```

must be added anywhere in your documentation (if you are using roxygen2) or this line in NAMESPACE

```
importFrom(Rdpack,reprompt)
```

if you maintain NAMESPACE manually